# Trying to add an Image using FacebookMediaObject with Visual Basic on the Facebook ADS Api

Tags: vb.net, facebook

I've been having a problem adding an AdGroup using the FacebookMediaObject in Visual Basic to create a new add using the Facebook ADS Api.

I understand not many people have access to it, but I hope someone here can shedd a light on it.

```
    Dim objAuthorizer As Authorizer = New Authorizer
    Dim objFB As FacebookClient = New FacebookClient(objAuthorizer.Session.AccessToken)

    Dim objParametersTargeting As Object = New ExpandoObject()
    Dim arrCountries() As String
    ReDim arrCountries(0)
    arrCountries(0) = "NL"
    objParametersTargeting.countries = arrCountries

    Dim objCreative As Object = New ExpandoObject()
    objCreative.title = "Test Adgroup title"
    objCreative.body = "Test Adgroup body"
    objCreative.link_url = "www.test.com"
    objCreative.image_file = "testcups.jpg"

    Dim strFilename As String = "C:\Upload\testcups.jpg"

    Dim objAdgroupParameters() As Object
    ReDim objAdgroupParameters(0)
    objAdgroupParameters(0) = New ExpandoObject()
    objAdgroupParameters(0).campaign_id = "123456789" 
    objAdgroupParameters(0).name = "Test adgroup"
    objAdgroupParameters(0).bid_type = 1
    objAdgroupParameters(0).max_bid = 50

    objAdgroupParameters(0).targeting = objParametersTargeting
    objAdgroupParameters(0).creative = objCreative

    Dim fbUplImage = New Facebook.FacebookMediaObject
    fbUplImage.FileName = "testcups.jpg"
    fbUplImage.ContentType = "image/png"
    Dim objBytes As Byte() = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(strFilename)
    fbUplImage.SetValue(objBytes)

    Dim objParameters As Object = New ExpandoObject()
    objParameters.method = "ads.createAdGroups"
    objParameters.account_id = "123456789"
    objParameters.adgroup_specs = objAdgroupParameters

    objParameters.image = fbUplImage

    Dim objResult As Object = objFB.Post(objParameters)
```

Of course the Account ID and the Campaign ID have to be valid ID's (which are valid ID's in my local source) and the file has to exist on your harddrive (which also is there on my local drive).

I keep getting the following results back:

```
{"updated_adgroups":[],"failed_adgroups":[{"spec_number":"0","errors":["Filesystem entity `/testcups.jpg' does not exist."]}]}
```

Anybody out there has any clue?

Thanks in advance,
Bas

---

Some extra info:
I found out (with a HTTP sniffer) that the Facebook C# SDK isn't making a Multipart Post requestout o

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried switching "fbUplImage.ContentType = "image/png" to image/jpg?